# Insert search text via jquery into the SharePoint 2013 "Find an Item" text box and trigger search

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am trying to programmatically trigger a search using the Find an Item search box within SharePoint 2013.

The plan is to insert text into the search box (an input control) using jquery and then trigger the search button click.

The text gets inserted ok but the button click does nothing. It appears that the text has not been pushed through to the input fully as when i click on the search box the text disappears. Any help would be great.

The same code works when targeting the standard sharepoint search box.

```
var input = $("#inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ1_lsinput");
$(input[0]).val("some text");
var btn = $("#inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ1_lsimg")
btn.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a text into the search text box and press the search button, SharePoint redirect you to the corresponding result page .aspx with a query string parameter ?k=something.

You can see then the "something" text into the search text box.
If you press the search button again but now into the search result page, SharePoint keep the query string ?k=something and add a hash parameter #k=something.

I don't know why SharePoint don't use the hash parameter at first time instead of the query string, but it works any way.

So, using JavaScript, instead of insert the the text and then press the button, just redirect the user to "http://sharepointsite/resultpage.aspx#k=something"
Once in the result page, you can continue changing the query by JavaScript:

```
var newHashQuery = "#k=" + encodeURIComponent("something 2");
window.location.hash = newHashQuery;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inplace SearchBox is dynamic control, which is created by *sp.ui.listsearchboxbootstrap.js*

To set value and click the button you should set value

```
var input = $("#inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ1_lsinput");
$(input[0]).val("some text");
```

Then you have to fire the 'input' event to initialize an internal control variables, like $z_3 (previous value of input), $9_3 (isDirty) - see *sp.ui.listsearchbox.dubug.js*, like this:

```
var ev = document.createEvent("Event");
ev.initEvent('input', true, true)
input.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

After that actions you can fire click event

```
var btn = $("#inplaceSearchDiv_WPQ1_lsimg")
btn.click();
```